# How do you NOT sync contacts when adding a new google account on Android?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, sync, google-contacts

By the time you add a new google account it adds the contacts already and you have to uncheck the option but its too late. Its running **lollipop**

Answer (score 0):

That's almost a chicken-and-egg problem: you cannot disable sync before the data are already gone, and you cannot create the new account offline to prevent this. But there are two apporaches which should work:

1. create the account and turn sync off *before* you save any contacts/calendars (not always possible; I assume you are speaking of an additionbal account while already using the device for a while)
2. have your contacts/calendar data in a separate calendar/addressbook which is not synced. To achieve this,

   - either use the "device only" storage (if your device offers that)
   - there's e.g. [offline calendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.droidwave.offlinecalendar) for calendar. And there's [DAVDroid](https://f-droid.org/packages/at.bitfire.davdroid/) (and probably other DAV-based sync tools) creating its own calendar and contact storage.

You should then make this other storage the "default storage" so that, whenever you add a contact/calendar entry, it will be saved there. Now you'd also need to move your data over to the new storage. For contacts, you could e.g. export them to a `.vcf` file (the contacts app offers that), then delete them all, then import the .vcf into the "other address book". For calendars, there's no such export possibility, unfortunately, though the `.ical` format could take care for that.

The easiest way of course would be not to create a Google account …